# embedded jetty server in a exploded war

Tags: java, servlets, embedded-jetty, contextpath

After successfully able to run a WAR through jetty, I am trying to embed jetty server into my web-application. It is a normal java application consisting servlet. I have used exploded WAR directory (WARless).

But I get the following exception.

```
    2014-02-22 16:27:08.271:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
    2014-02-22 16:27:08.319:WARN:oejs.Holder:
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ClientServlet
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at com.jetty.RunJetty.main(RunJetty.java:24)
    2014-02-22 16:27:08.321:WARN:/:unavailable
```

Embedded jetty Server code

```
    package com.jetty;

    import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
    import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

    public class RunJetty {

    public RunJetty() {
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Server server=new Server(8080);
    WebAppContext wac = new WebAppContext();
    wac.setResourceBase("C:/Users/User/j2ee/workspace/CLient1");
    wac.setDescriptor("C:/Users/User/j2ee/workspace/CLient1/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml");
    wac.setContextPath("/");
    wac.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
    server.setHandler(wac);
    try {
        server.start();
        server.join();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    }
```

Servlet Code

```
    package com.jetty;

    import java.io.IOException;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import org.omg.CORBA.RepositoryIdHelper;

    public class ClientServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8120079003868426157L;
    private String greeting="Hello World";

    public ClientServlet(){}
    public ClientServlet(String greeting)
    {
    this.greeting=greeting;
    }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    response.getWriter().println("<h1>"+greeting+"</h1>");

    }

    }
```

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>kajh</display-name>

    <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>ClientServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ClientServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ClientServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ClientServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ClientServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

Additionally, I want to use response.sendRedirect in my servlet. Something like,

```
      public class ClientServlet extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8120079003868426157L;
private String greeting="Hello World";

public ClientServlet(){}
public ClientServlet(String greeting)
{
    this.greeting=greeting;
}
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/CLient1/index.html");

}
}
```

Please help! I am stuck on this like forever.
Thank you in advance!

Also I am adding the folder structure of my application to have a better understanding

[image]

Comment: Looks like ClassServlet is not on your classpath? Are you running from an IDE like Eclipse or commandline? Apart from that, this could be a good start for your Java EE with Jetty: https://github.com/jhannes/java-ee-turnkey

Comment: RunJetty and ClientServlet are inside the same package. I am using eclipse to run this application. Do you mean that I make servlet as a separate java app and covert into a jar and put in classpath of RunJetty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the servlet-class should be

```
<servlet-class>com.jetty.ClientServlet</servlet-class>
```

Edit: Made it show the codeformat also.

Comment: yes RunJetty and ClientServlet are inside the same package. Still not working!!

:(

Comment: @ParulS seems like the codeformatting was not included. I think you have to edit your web.xml according to the answer

Comment: I used <servlet-class>com.jetty.ClientServlet</servlet-class>
and now I am not getting any exception. Still I am not able to use 

`response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/CLient1/index.html");`

I get the following exception when hitting the URL **http://localhost:8080/ClientServlet**

_HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /CLient1/index.html. Reason:

    Not Found
Powered by Jetty:/_

Comment: I have also included my application structure in my question. Your help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think there's a number of reasons to consider now. 1. your resourceBase is wrong. It should point to Webcontent. 2. Clientl is not in your web.xml url, and probably shouldn't be. 3. Perhaps remove the servlet all together and use web.xml xml tag welcome-list to point to index.html

Comment: 4. Is this some proof of concept or a student task or a real productioncase? I could/would have some pointers if it's the latter :)

Comment: It is a proof of concept for production. But it seems that I have figured out the issue. I have placed the html pages inside WebContent. But I have done the following in RunJetty.java
`wac.setResourceBase("C:/Users/User/j2ee/workspace/CLient1");
`
I changed the above LOC to `wac.setResourceBase("C:/Users/User/j2ee/workspace/CLient1/WebContent");`
and the issue is resolved. In case you have a better insight, please suggest. Thanks a ton for all the help extended. :)

Comment: I see and glad to be of help. I would also highly recommend https://github.com/bekkopen/jetty-pkg and https://github.com/jhannes/java-ee-turnkey if you're serious about a real production scenario. Both of the examples needs a bit tweaking to run from Eclipse, but not much. Maybe I'll throw in a commit to the repos to make it Eclipsy :)